# Email delivery issues

Tags: email, plesk

I have had some issues with email delivery from my business domain.

I moved over to Socketlabs and sent emails with them but after a while I had the same issues.

I was advised by socketlabs to set up a bounce domain (involved pointing bounce.domain.com to tracking.socketlabs.com via CNAME record)

I was also advised to activate the response column which gives a response code similar to -

`250 2.6.0 <cbdb7d3a-f296-3ee7-033b-dbd7b85b4295@domain.com> [InternalId=15650860832168, Hostname=AM6PR02MB4581.eurprd02.prod.outlook.com] 43817 bytes in 8.318, 5.144 KB/sec Queued mail for delivery{CRLF}`

or

`250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as F0BE371ABB2_E83038CF{CRLF}`

So... What I suppose I am asking is... rather than paying for an email relay which seems to be giving the same results as what I am getting using my own email server through plesk... Is there a way which I can add this functionality to my own email server set up.

IT doesn't need to be as in-depth. But ideally, I would like to be able to check the delivery status of the emails and if need be the response code.

The bounce domain is also something which I am curious about, Is this something which is required/recommended?

Comment: Email delivery issues is a huge topic, more than could be addressed in a few paragraphs here.